# Нотификация, запускающая приложение

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification, eventbus

Задача такая: имеется сервис, которые посылает сообщения с помощью EventBus. Получает это сообщение класс потомок Application и должен создать Нотификацию, по нажатию на которую будет запускаться активити. Приложение будет в этот момент свернуто, никаких запущенных активити Что-то я не соображу. Во всех примерах нотификация создается из активити. А как ее создать без активити и сделать так, чтобы активити запускалось уже по нажатию на нее?

Comment: А почему бы не отображать нотификацию прямо из сервиса? Зачем там лишние действия EventBus -> Application?

Comment: Разобралась, можно из application то же самое сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать нотификацию из Application. Там тоже есть context.

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ кодом.